# Pip update the wrong python folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, anaconda

The first time I have installed Python on my machine, it was Spyder with Anaconda.
But, with this version, I wasn't able to install pyodbc.
So, I have install Visual Studio Code and everything works fine

But today, I have tried to update some libraries (like certify or scipy) but each time I use pip install, I update my Anaconda folder and not my WindowsApps folder.

So, when I use PIP, how to update the Windows folder and not Anaconda. And also how to remove Anaconda from my computer. In my Windows Settings, I have no app related to Anaconda (weird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your path, and which `pip` executable is being executed.

If you run it with the full path to your install in WindowsApps, then it should detect and update that version.

Comment: Thanks for the tips to write the full path. It works perfectly like that

Answer (score 1):

You can check which pip you are using with the command of `pip --version`.

Press `win` to open the start menu and search `uninstall-a` to find the `Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe` or open the `control-panel` to uninstall it. Like the [official docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) recommended.

Comment: Good catch. The uninstall of Anaconda was easy like that